# R command `group_by`

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am not able to understand exactly how this code works. I have found it on a tutorial guide:

[Data manipulation in R - Steph Locke](https://itsalocke.com/files/DataManipulationinR.pdf)

on page 133 an example that I am able to understand only partially.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)

flights %>%
group_by(month, carrier) %>%
summarise(n=n()) %>%  ##sum of items;
group_by(month) %>%                             
mutate(prop=scales::percent(n/sum(n)), n=NULL) %>%              
spread(month, prop)


flights %>%
group_by(month, carrier) %>%    ## This is grouping by months and within the months by carrier;
summarise(n=n()) %>%        ## It is summing the items, giving for each month and each carrier the sum of items;
```

At this point there in another `group_by()`, it looks like a nested to `group_by(month, carrier)`

Then:

```
mutate(prop=scales::percent(n/sum(n)), n=NULL) %>%  ## Calculates the percentage of items over the total and store them in "prop"
```

Last line it creates the matrix, putting in the columns `month` and inside the value obtained from `prop`

I would like to understand better what is doing exactly the second `group_by(month) %>%`

Thank you in advance for every reply.

Comment: `spread` is just doing reshaping to wide format and not creating a matrix.  The second group by is just updating the group attribute to a single column  which is not really needed as by default `summarise` uses `drop_last` i..e the `carrier` is not in the group attribute after the first summarise.  You can remove the second group_by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second `group_by` is not needed here as by default `summarise` step argument `.groups = "drop_last"`.  Therefore, after the first `summarise`, there is only a single grouping column i.e. 'month' remains.  We can change the code to

```
flights %>%
  group_by(month, carrier) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  mutate(prop=scales::percent(n/sum(n)), n=NULL)
```

---

Suppose, we change the default value in `.groups` to "drop", then, it will drop all the grouping variables, and thus a new group_by statement is needed.  Also, after the last grouping statement, if we are using `mutate`, it wouldn't drop the group attributes and thus `ungroup` would be useful

```
flights %>%
  group_by(month, carrier) %>%
  summarise(n=n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
  group_by(month) %>%
  mutate(prop=scales::percent(n/sum(n)), n=NULL) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: Now I understand. The output from summarise is a table (`tibble`) vith variables: `month`, `carrier`, `n`. This `group_by` to make another group from this last table (which in this case is not needed because it is implicit in `summarise`).